# How to do a custom query from a parameter input

Tags: java, mongodb

Hi I am currently trying to do a custom query that can be inputed via a parameter in my repository layer.

```
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.MongoRepository;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;



@Repository
 public interface LinuxServerTaniumReportRepository extends MongoRepository<LinuxServerTaniumReport, String> {

@Query(:query)
public List<LinuxServerTaniumReport> performQuery(String query);
}
```

how should I go about this?

Answer (score 0):

You can not do this via Annotation, but you can do this by providing a custom repository. It is something around this lines:

```
public interface MyCustomExecuteMethod<T> extends Repository {

    public List<T> performQuery(String query);

} 

public class MyCustomExecuteMethodProvider<T> implements MyCustomExecuteMethod {
   @Autowire
   EntityManager em;

   public List<T> performQuery(String query) {
      // put your logic here where you create the query via the entity manager 
   }

}


Repository
 public interface LinuxServerTaniumReportRepository extends MongoRepository<LinuxServerTaniumReport, String> ,MyCustomExecuteMethod<LinuxServerTaniumReport>{

}
```

Now the only thing you need to get this method is to extend your repositories with the interface MyCustomExecuteMethod.
This technic is called spring data composable repositories it is covered in spring data documentation under chapter Custome Implementation of spring data repositories https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.custom-implementations